# code ping time meter - is this really true?

Tags: mysql

I am using a sort of code_ping for the time it took to process the whole page, to all my pages in my webportal.

I figured if I do a $count_start in the header initialised with current timestamp and a $count_end in the footer, the same, the difference is a meter to roughly let me know how well optimised the page is (queries, loading time of all things in that particular page).

Say for one page i get 0.0075 seconds, for others I get 0.045 etc...i'm working on optimising the queries better this way.

My question is. If one page says by this meter "rough loading time" that has 0.007 seconds,
will 1000 users querying the same page at the same time get each the result in 0.007 * 1000 = 7 seconds ? meaning they will each get the page after 7 seconds ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, it doesn't usually mean that.

The missing variable in your equation is how your database *and* your application server *and* anything else in your stack handles [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29).

To illustrate this strictly from the MySQL perspective, I wrote a test client program that establishes a fixed number of connections to the MySQL server, each in its own thread (and so, able to issue a query to the server at approximately the same time).

Once all of the threads have signaled back that they are connected, a message is sent to all of them at the same time, to send their query.

When each thread gets the "go" signal, it looks at the current system time, then sends the query to the server.  When it gets the response, it looks at the system time again, and then sends all of the information back to the main thread, which compares the timings and generates the output below.

The program is written in such a way that it does not count the time required to establish the connections to the server, since in a well-behaved application the connections would be reusable.

The query was `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(1) FROM ...` (an InnoDB table with about 500 rows in it).

```
threads  1 min 0.001089 max 0.001089 avg 0.001089 total runtime 0.001089
threads  2 min 0.001200 max 0.002951 avg 0.002076 total runtime 0.003106
threads  4 min 0.000987 max 0.001432 avg 0.001176 total runtime 0.001677
threads  8 min 0.001110 max 0.002789 avg 0.001894 total runtime 0.003796
threads 16 min 0.001222 max 0.005142 avg 0.002707 total runtime 0.005591
threads 32 min 0.001187 max 0.010924 avg 0.003786 total runtime 0.014812
threads 64 min 0.001209 max 0.014941 avg 0.005586 total runtime 0.019841
```

Times are in seconds.  The min/max/avg are the best/worst/average times observed running the same query.  At a concurrency of 64, you notice the best case wasn't all that different than the best case with only 1 query.  But biggest take-away here is the total runtime column.  That value is the difference in time from when the first thread sent its query (they all send their query at essentially the same time, but "precisely" the same time is impossible since I don't have a 64-core machine to run the test script on) to when the last thread received its response.

Observations: the good news is that the 64 queries taking an average of 0.005586 seconds definitely did not require 64 * 0.005586 seconds = 0.357504 seconds to execute... it didn't even require 64 * 0.001089 (the best case time) = 0.069696  All of those queries were started and finished within 0.019841 seconds... or only about 28.5% of the time it would have theoretically taken for them to run one-after-another.

The bad news, of course, is that the average execution time on this query at a concurrency of 64 is over 5 times as high as the time when it's only run once... and the worst case is almost 14 times as high.  But that's still far better than a linear extrapolation from the single-query execution time would suggest.

Things don't scale indefinitely, though.  As you can see, the performance does deteriorate with concurrency and at some point it would go downhill -- probably fairly rapidly -- as we reached whichever bottleneck occurred first.  The number of tables, the nature of the queries, any locking that is encountered, all contribute to how the server performs under concurrent loads, as do the performance of your storage, the size, performance, and architecture, of the system's memory, and the internals of MySQL -- some of which can be tuned and some of which can't.

But of course, the database isn't the only factor.  The way the application server handles concurrent requests can be another big part of your performance under load, sometimes to a larger extent than the database, and sometimes less.

One big unknown from your benchmarks is how much of that time is spent by the database answering the queries, how much of the time is spent by the application server executing the logic business, and how much of the time is spent by the code that is rendering the page results into HTML.

Comment: thanks Michael, you cover exactly what I needed, meaning the exact database query section. i'm now sleeping much better knowing these stats you just posted :) thanks again for the thoroughness :)