# Python: Dealing with MySQL connect hanging

Tags: python, mysql, timeout, database-connection, freeze

I am starting a large number of python jobs simultaneously on a cloud computing provider (about 320 jobs). Each of the python jobs makes a few connections to a MySQL server when they start. The connections complete successfully for most jobs, but there are always a few that hang when connecting. Examining the backtrace of the hung jobs with gdb shows the backtrace below, which seems to indicate that the process is hung waiting for a response from MySQL.

Is there any way I can fix the hanging, either on the MySQL side or the Python side?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f64612d14cc in recv () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004fb139 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000510b4b in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000004cbb0a in PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs ()
#4  0x00007f645e2ee69c in API_recvSocket (sock=0x4f03d00, buffer=0x7f644774b010 "",     cbBuffer=cbBuffer@entry=65536) at ./python/io_cpython.c:229
#5  0x00007f645e2ef1c0 in Connection::readSocket (this=this@entry=0x5301720) at     ./lib/Connection.cpp:153
#6  0x00007f645e2ef264 in Connection::recvPacket (this=this@entry=0x5301720) at     ./lib/Connection.cpp:354
#7  0x00007f645e2efd84 in Connection::connect (this=0x5301720, _host=<optimized out>,     _port=<optimized out>, _username=<optimized out>,
    _password=<optimized out>, _database=<optimized out>, _autoCommit=0x0,     _charset=MCS_utf8_general_ci) at ./lib/Connection.cpp:487
#8  0x00007f645e2ee8aa in UMConnection_Connect (conn=<optimized out>, _host=<optimized     out>, _port=<optimized out>, _username=<optimized out>,
    _password=<optimized out>, _database=<optimized out>, _autoCommit=0x0, _charset=33)     at ./lib/capi.cpp:84
#9  0x00007f645e2ed74e in Connection_connect (self=0x510fcd8, args=<optimized out>) at     ./python/umysql.c:860
#10 0x00000000004ac5ce in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#11 0x00000000004b3fd8 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#12 0x00000000004b4b4c in ?? ()
#13 0x0000000000481cc4 in ?? ()
#14 0x00000000004613b4 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000463cc2 in ?? ()
#16 0x00000000004acc66 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#17 0x00000000004acde0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#18 0x00000000004b3fd8 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#19 0x00000000004acb98 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#20 0x00000000004b3fd8 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#21 0x0000000000536723 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000000446bf2 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#23 0x00000000004470ec in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#24 0x0000000000447cdc in Py_Main ()
#25 0x00007f64606b6ead in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`
#26 0x00000000004c7f39 in _start ()
```

Answer (score 0):

[*Default number of connections in MySQL is 150*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html), you might want to raise it a bit and see if if it helps.

Comment: If you mean max_connections, I have it set at 10000 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to increase the values of the system variables [`back_log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_back_log) and [`thread_cache_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size).

The `back_log` is the limit on the number of unserviced, pending connection requests waiting for the initial connection (default 50) and `thread_cache_size` is the maximum number of OS threads that will be placed into a pool for reuse, after a client disconnects, allowing faster acceptance of subsequent connections, since the OS doesn't have to create an actual thread for each incoming connection, if there's one in the pool (default 0).  (Each client connection always has its own thread).

Don't go nuts with that one, since any extra memory needed for prior queries run by the thread 
may remain allocated to the thread when it's set aside for reuse, instead of being freed when the thread is destroyed... so you don't want this value so large that the OS threads are never destroyed, tempting though that might seem.  Just a handful, maybe 1 or 2 per CPU core will probably help.

Comment: That makes sense, especially back_log. I'll try increasing it

Comment: When I wrote the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17895136/1695906) I found that my script exhibited the behavior you describe (except not python) when I tried to spin up a large number of connections at the same time..  IIRC, I went with thread_cache_size, since it allowed the connections from the benchmarking code to set up faster, since thread creation does take time, and I suspect a global mutex may be involved, imposing a finite limit on it, but I'm speculating.  In your case, definitely try back_log, but the other may help get things rolling faster, too.

Comment: is there any instruction how to do this?